# Socket Programming readStream!.takeUnretainedValue() takes infinite time

Tags: python, ios, iphone, swift, sockets

I am trying to implement a Socket based chat application using Swift in frontend language and Python for back-end. I followed the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server and implemented socket in terminal and connected using telnet localhost 80 and connected successfully to the server socket. But when I tried to communicate to the server socket from iPhone application it's never getting connected. My code is

```
var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "localhost", 80, &readStream,   &writeStream)
if readStream != nil && writeStream != nil {
   inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()// program halts here and not going to next line
   outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
}
self.inputStream.delegate = self
self.outputStream.delegate = self
self.inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
self.outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode:     NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
self.inputStream.open()
self.outputStream.open()
```

Execution of code stops when it reaches the line

```
inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
```

So what is to be done to execute the program correctly and get a call onto the server.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I was using

```
var inputStream = NSInputStream()
var outputStream = NSOutputStream()
```

instead of

```
var inputStream: NSInputStream!
var outputStream: NSOutputStream!
```

and replacing them solved my issue.